# Calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} x^2\exp(-a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})d\mathbf{x}$ without spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, computer-algebra-systems

Which tool can I use to (numerically?) evaluate

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\exp\left(-a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right) dx ~ dy ~ dz,~a>0
$$

without having to transform to spherical coordinates first?

I tried [SymPy](https://live.sympy.org/) online without success:

```
a = symbols('a', positive=True)
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
integrate(x**2*exp(-a*sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)), (x, -oo, oo), (y, -oo, oo), (z, -oo, oo))
```

If I transform to spherical coordinates, it evaluates without problems:

```
a = symbols('a', positive=True)
r, theta, phi = symbols('r theta phi')
integrate(r**2*sin(theta)*r**2*sin(theta)**2*cos(phi)**2*exp(-a*r), (r, 0, oo), (theta, 0, pi), (phi, 0, 2*pi))
```

$$
\frac{32\pi}{a^5}
$$

Comment: Why do you refuse to use the correct approach to solve the problem?

Comment: Spherical coordinates *is* the shortcut.

Comment: @TedShifrin Are you saying that there is no way for a computer to numerically evaluate the first integral by iterating over x, y, z?

Comment: For numerical evaluation you might want e.g. a coordinate transformation that would bring the domain of integration to a bounded one, and then use your favourite quadrature formulas. But you prohibit even *spherical* coordinates...

Comment: In fact before directly applying spherical coordinates, I would exploit the symmetry further and note that this is a third of the integral of $\|x\|^2\exp(-a\|x\|)$, and now invoke the change of variables to spherical coordinates.